# Wordpress plugin for external DB login

Tags: wordpress

Do any one know

any word press plugin that can used for external dB login ,apart from word press plugin

'**External DB authentication**' because it is not compactable for word press latest version 3.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed the [External DB authentication](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/) plugin successfully, with a fresh installation of Wordpress 3.0.4. I have also been able to configure it and use it without any problem.

Could you please post the errors or problems you have encountered when you tried to install it?

I didn't know this plugin in fact, but works great, good to know about it!

Comment: I tried version 3.0.4. and installed the plug in 'External DB authentication'.But i can login with the first record that i have typed from the new DB.Other accounts are not working.ANd there is no such problem for version 2.9.2.Also in the description this plugin they says it compactable upto 2.9.2 ,right side(http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-database-authentication/)

Comment: @Linto: Are you authenticating against another WP DB? The plugin works fine, but you can't easily login against another WP DB version 3.0.4. The password generation has changed, it is not MD5 or SHA1, which are the only options given on the plugin's settings page.

Comment: @Ajweb.Iam trying to login against a MSSQL DB (not a WP DB)of another server.But while i try to login after enable  the plugin it goes blank.But  while i connect to MYSQL DB it works.Any idea?

Comment: I suppose you have already installed the "MDB2 PEAR database abstraction package and relevant database drivers" as the readme indicates? If so, I would try to debug it by allowing error reporting and display errors and/or inserting some print() calls (you can start by echoing the MDB2 SQL query around line 315 in the ext_db_auth.php file).

Comment: Firstly thank you for your help that you have been given.I am getting the error "Failed to issue query, error message : MDB2 Error: unknown error", while taking the login page.And i have given echo on line 315(ext_db_auth.php file) and i get the query as " SET NAMES 'utf8'".Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Ajweb Also, will you please give your chat id, so that i can chat

Comment: @Ajweb Thank you very muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.i got the solution.You are the person to make me think like that. the query " SET NAMES 'utf8'" was not working in MSSQL SERVER.that was the problem .So i have commented the lines 348,349 (ext_db_auth.php file) according to a post in internet.Now its start to work.Thank you once again Ajweb

Comment: Well, the solution was yours really! But I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://www.cedricve.me/blog/2011/07/18/how-to-make-use-of-wordpress-passwords/
It explains how you can make an external login with the credentials of a wordpress installation.

I hope this can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Incase you wanted different features, that plugin didn't quite do everything I needed so I created my own called [External Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-login/):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-login/

If there's something it doesn't do that you require let me know as I'm always open to ideas on how to improve it.